# Документация Java (Android) в Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, ide, java

Начал изучать Android, в качестве IDE использую Intellij IDEA, до этого писал на C# в VS. 
Где найти комментарии или документацию к классам и методам в стандартных пакетах Android? В  VS, например, при наведении на неизвестный класс или метод отображается подсказка-описание, которое помогает понять что к чему. А в Android (или точнее будет Java) как что-то подобное осуществить? Интересует именно подсказки в IDE , а не ссылки к оф. документации Android http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html и все в таком духе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Советую ознакомиться с IDEA keymap: [Windows/Linux](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf), [Mac](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf)

По нажатию ctrl+Q с кареткой на имени метода/класса вызывается quick documetation popup

Comment: Quick documentation popup я уже обнаружил, а чтобы этот попап всплывал всегда настроить можно? все настройки пролазил - не нашел пока

Comment: а зачем всегда ему всплывать? В jdk имена методов всегда говорящие и в IDEA автодополнение понимает контекст и выдает наиболее релевантные результаты, а если нужно увидеть детали реализации, то комбинацию из двух клавиш нажать достаточно быстро.